# How to add content to Power Point slides programmatically using Officer?

Tags: r, for-loop, flextable, officer

I am creating a Power Point presentation using Officer with tables created programmatically. The data varies all the time so my goal is to do it using a for loop or something else.

In the example below I have 3 `flextable` objects stored in a list. In my real problem these will be a larger number of tables (usually >30 tables). I also need each slide to contain one table.

Then, I create a slide and use a for loop to add each table to a slide. However at this point I get the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("ph_with", value) : 
  no applicable method for 'ph_with' applied to an object of class "list"
```

When selecting or unlisting items from a list the object class is no longer `flextable` and the function `ph_with()` does not like that. I have also tried to use `unlist` but get the same error.

Is there any way to run `ph_with()` programmatically, adding 1 item (table and/or chart) per slide?

Thank you

```r
library(magrittr)
library(officer)
library(flextable)


# Areate tables (in my code these are create programmatically using a for loop)
ft1 <- qflextable(head(airquality))
ft2 <- qflextable(head(ggplot2::diamonds))
ft3 <- qflextable(head(mtcars))


# Atore flextables in a list
table_list <- list(ft1, ft2, ft3)


# Create slide
my_pres <- read_pptx() 

# Add 1 table per slide from the list created previously
for(i in 1:length(table_list)) {
   
   my_pres <- my_pres %>% 
      add_slide(my_pres, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
      ph_with(table_list[i], location = ph_location_type(type = "body"))
   
   }



# I get an error here!!!
# Error in UseMethod("ph_with", value) : 
#  no applicable method for 'ph_with' applied to an object of class "list"


print(my_pres, target = "My_presentation.pptx")
```

Comment: Use `table_list[[i]]` instead to extract the plot object from the list.

Comment: Ok, that was easy. Thanks!